# Chrome does not support UseSubmitBehavior="true", any alternatives?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome

When change `UseSubmitBehavior="true"` for my asp button, it not not fire up the `Onclick function`.

For example, I have:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Create!" UseSubmitBehavior="true" />
```

This works in IE and Firefox, but in Chrome the button becomes unusable. Any way to fix that?
I do need to use the submitbehavior.